# dev-container & createFileSystemWatcher behaviour

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

I am writing an extension which creates a file system watcher - this simply watches for (create,changes) on a file that gets updated when a specific tool is run. This is part of a TreeDataProvider for a view (See image)

[image]

```
        this.fsWatcher = workspace.createFileSystemWatcher("**/*.dependencies");
        this.fsWatcher.onDidCreate((_item) => {
            this.refresh();
        });
        this.fsWatcher.onDidChange((_item) => {
            this.refresh();
        });
```

This has worked nicely in native invocations of vscode, and when remote on ssh and wsl platforms (the image above if wsl2)

However I am creating a dev-container at the moment, and with that container I am finding that the tree isn't updating. It appears that the File System watcher isn't actually triggering. Perhaps it isn't watching the right place (the workspace is the default mounted local directory in the container) or because of the indirection of docker/containerisation it isn't doing the right thing?

Has anyone had this issue and solved it? or am I doing something wrong here?